# What does "user account" in samba share actually mean?

Tags: networking, permissions, login, samba

I'm returning to Ubuntu after many years, but in my LAN I still need some machines with Windows 7.

Right now I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 and I want to share a folder. I did the following steps:

1. browse to the desired folder
2. right click and select "share"
3. enable the sharing (it installed samba) and the read/write access (but *not* the free access flag)

Because my installation is in Italian, I don't know the exact words in the English version, I hope it's clear what I'm saying.

Then I powered up my Windows machine and in the network places I saw my Ubuntu machine. Double click and it showed the shared folder. To enter it, it requested a login. Good.

Well, I entered the username/password of my Ubuntu user, because the "free access" flag says: "who haven't a user account". I have it, and I know the credentials, but they are refused.

Hence, I wonder what does "user account" actually mean in this context.
It isn't referred to the Ubuntu account (the owner of the shared folder) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I entered the username/password of my Ubuntu user

Unlike Windows where there is just the one user in Linux there are two. One for local logins and the other for samba.

You need to add the local user ( mark for example ) to the samba password database:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a mark
```

Comment: Yep, this did the trick. However, I'm a bit confused. I was used to do this by hand when I configured samba from command line. But using the GUI, should not sync the user itself?

Comment: A long time ago there used to be a package that was automatically installed ( libpam-smbpass if I remember correctly ) that would automatically do this. But that was removed.